# styling a form with css

Tags: css

First time here.
I would like to style a form using css but has failed completely. The form is at http://opm.nulep.org/2012-10-17-04-17-46/alrep.html

I would like the fields to be in vertical columns.

Comment: Please include your code in the post.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/style-web-forms-css/

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this case, I would recommend using `<div>`s that are each 25% width or tables. Tables are generally bulkier and are **not recommended**, though I am mentioning them purely for the purpose of giving you a choice.

If you want to use a four-column layout with `<div>`s, try something like this:

```
<form>
    <div style="width: 25%; float: left;">Contractor options here...</div>
    <div style="width: 25%; float: left;">District options here...</div>
    <div style="width: 25%; float: left;">Subcounty options here...</div>
    <div style="width: 25%; float: left;">End date options here...</div>
</form>
```

I would recommend moving the `style` options to either an external stylesheet or internal stylesheet (so either a stylesheet.css file or just to the top of the file between `<style>` tags).

For tables, follow something like this:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Contractor options here...</td>
            <td>District options here...</td>
            <td>Subcounty options here...</td>
            <td>End date here...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Again, I don't recommend using tables for layout, as it's a better practice to use them for actual [tabular data](http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm), but beginners usually find that tables can be easier to use.

Good luck.

Comment: Please don't recommend tables for non tabular data.

Comment: @Andy I don't mean to sound rude, but I know plenty of cases where tables have been used for non-tabular data--while it's not the standard, and generally frowned upon, it is an option for beginning web developers. My preference would be the divs, but whatever comes easier is probably whatever should be used. Perhaps I'm a complete idiot and totally wrong, but I think people should use what they are comfortable with.

Comment: It's all well and good telling people to use what they are comfortable with, but there is no point getting someone into bad practice from the very start. Professional developers will never use tables for non-data, and neither should new people. I would argue they are harder (and more annoying) to layout than plain divs, especially for OP's example

Comment: @Andy I agree that they are more difficult, and I agree that it's better to get them into good habits early, so I can rearrange my answer and add a note about it, but in all honesty, I would still like them to know that tables are an option, however bad an option that would be.

Answer (score 1):

You should put each h3 & dropdown div in a floating div with a width of 200px. A right margin (for the first two div wrappers) of 6px keeps a little distance between the 3 of them.

html (4 times):

```
<div class="dropdown_wrapper">
  <h3 ...>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

inside css stylesheet:

```
.dropdown_wrapper { float: left; width: 200px; margin-right: 6px; }
.dropdown_wrapper:last-child { margin-right: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean having the three next to each other on a single line?

In which case you could wrap your h3 and div for each field in another div, that would have aapprox. a 300px width and a float.

html

```
<form>
   <div class="column">
      <h3>...</h3>
      <div>form item</div>
   </div>
   <div class="column">
      <h3>...</h3>
      <div>form item</div>
   </div>
   <div class="column last">
      <h3>...</h3>
      <div>form item</div>
   </div>
</form>
```

css

```
.column {float: left; width : 300px; margin-right : 10px;}
.last {margin-right: 0;}
```

then you adjust the width and margin to fit with your mother div!

Comment: May I suggest including example code?

Comment: here you go! it's edited

Comment: Much better! Good code, as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use tables or some floated divs.
Each solution has pros and cons.

Div solution:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .column { width: 200px; float: left; }
    .clear { clear: both }
</style>
<form>
    <div class="column">
        <input />
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <input />
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Table:

```html
<form>
    <table>
        <td>
            <input />
            ...
        </td>
        <td>
            <input />
            ...
        </td>
    </table>
</form>
```